# Android unique device ID from native code

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, uniqueidentifier

How to get the Android unique device ID from the native code (not from java)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this is to use JNI to call the Java APIs that supply this information.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this information using *libRIL* (Radio Interface Layer). Check the content of the directory */hardware/ril/libril* in android sources. Looking into the **com.android.internal.telephony.RIL** may also help you to understand how RIL requests are working.

Comment: Absolutely not.  That is a totally private API.  An app doing this will break, you can count on it.